# How to solve $(2p_1^2-2p_1+1)^n \le 2^{-10}$ where $p_1 = 1-(1-(1/n))^N$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let
$$S_{n,N}=(2p_1^2-2p_1+1)^n$$
and

$p_1 = 1-(1-(1/n))^N$.

I would like to solve $S_{n,N} \leq 2^{-10}$ for $n$.  This seems hard to do exactly but is there a good approximation one can find?

We can assume $n,N> 1$.

Comment: Are n, N integers?

Comment: @xidgel Yes they are but it might be too hard to take into account ?

Answer (score 0):

One reasonable approximaton, valid for large $n$, is $(1-\frac 1n)^n \approx e^{-1}$, so $p_1 \approx 1-e^{-\frac Nn}$  The approximation to $e^{-1}$ is low, so the approximation to $p_1$ will be high.

Comment: If you the solve for $n$ what do you get? It still doesn't seem obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

By solving for $p_1$, then solving for $N$, you can show that: 
**(a)** $n>=10$ is a constraint for valid solutions, and **(b)** valid values for $N$ are constrained by:

$$
\frac{ln \left[1/2 +\sqrt{(1/2)^{10/n+1} - 1/4}\  \right]}{ln(1-1/n)} \le N \le\frac{ln \left[1/2 -\sqrt{(1/2)^{10/n+1} - 1/4}\ \right]}{ln(1-1/n)}
$$

Then the solutions are fully specified.

Hope that helps.